# How to differentiate between operational and programmer errors in promise chains?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

So I want to know how to make sure that my Node application will crash if it comes upon a programmer error(undefined variable, reference error, syntax error...). However, if I am using promise chains then the final `catch()` will catch all possible errors including programmer errors.

For example:

```
PromiseA()
.then((result) => {
        foo.bar(); //UNDEFINED FUNCTION HERE!!!!!
        return PromiseB(result);
        })
.catch(
//handle errors here
)
```

Now the `catch()` statement will also catch the really bad error of an undefined function and then try to handle it. I need a way for my program to crash when it comes up against errors like these.

EDIT: I also just realized that even if I throw an error in the last catch it will just be consumed by the promise chain :-[. How am I supposed to deal with that?

Comment: This is the same problem as in Javascript without using promises, is it not?

Comment: Throw back any errors you aren't handling

Comment: How would I differentiate between them elegantly? Without long if else chains? There could be any number of types of operational errors that come from PromiseA or PromiseB.

Comment: With a `Map`, an object or even a switch.

Comment: An example please?

Comment: You should only `catch` the errors you are interested in handling. That's what the `catch` clause is for, to handle those specific errors so that your program can keep on working as normal. There's no need to handle ALL errors.

Comment: So my question is how do I differentiate and then rethrow the errors I don't want to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is to handle those errors that you can potentially recover from. These errors are usually something you throw in your code. For example, if an item is not found in a DB some libraries will throw an `Error`. They'll add a `type` property or some other property to differentiate the different type of errors.

You can also potentially subclass the `Error` class and use `instanceof` to differentiate each error.

```
 class myOwnError extends Error {}
```

Then:

```
Prom.catch(err => {
   if(err instanceof myOwnError){ /* handle error here */ }
   else { throw err; }
});
```

If you want to avoid if/chains, you can use a `switch` on `error.constructor`:

```
switch(err.constructor){
    case myOwnError:
    break;
    case someOtherError:
    break;
    default:
      throw err;
}
```

You can also use an a `Map` or regular objects by creating functions for each possible error and storing them. With a `Map`:

```
let m = new Map();
m.set(myOWnError, function(e){ /*handle error here*/ });
m.set(myOtherError, function(e){ /*handle other error here*/ });
```

Then just do:

```
Prom.catch(err => {
   let fn = m.get(err.constructor);
   if(fn){ return fn(err); }
   else { throw err; }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is I need to check if that error was made by the library by checking the type property. Will I be able to find this in the library's documentation? Also if I throw an error within a `catch()` statement it will be consumed by the chain and will not crash my program. How do I fix this? Finally is it normal for me to be concerned about having these other types of exceptions or am I just being paranoid? I have never seen an example of someone trying to safeguard against those errors.

Comment: Usually yes, they add extra information on the error objects they throw. Not all of them will though. If you throw an error within a `catch` and you never attached another `catch` to it then it will become an unhandled rejected promise. You can then do [this](https://medium.com/@dtinth/making-unhandled-promise-rejections-crash-the-node-js-process-ffc27cfcc9dd) if you want it to crash.

Comment: So is it common practice for me to worry about this? Am I being paranoid? I have seen no examples of someone trying to safeguard against errors like this.

Comment: Yes it is, no you aren't. People swallow errors with `catch` all the time and are left without any clue of what the heck just happened to their program.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Below is a description what we do at the company I work. The package linked is written by us.

What we do is to catch all errors and sort them into programmer and operational errors.

We've made small library to help us: https://www.npmjs.com/package/oops-error

For promise chains we use:

```
import { programmerErrorHandler } from 'oops-error'

...
export const doSomething = (params) => {
    somePromiseFunction().catch(programmerErrorHandler('failed to do something', {params}))
}
```

It marks the error as programmer error, adds 'failed to do something' as error message and adds the params as a context (for debugging later)

For errors that we know that can come up (person not found, validEmail, etc) we do something like

```
import { Oops } from 'oops-error'

export const sendEmail = (email) => {
    if(!isValidEmail(email)) {
        throw new Oops({
            message: 'invalid email',
            category: 'OperationalError',
            context: {
                email,
            },
        })
    }
    ...
}
```

At every level we show the error messages of Operational Errors. So a simple

```
.cath(e => {
  if (e.category == 'OperationalError') {
    // handle the gracefully
  }
  else {
    throw e // We will tackle this later
  }
}
```

And at the end of our request in express we have our final error handler, where catch the error, check if its operational and then show the error message, but not the actual context. If its a programmer error we stop the process (not ideal, but we don't want the user to keep messing with broken code)

Comment: Thanks, this makes me feel a bit better about not being completely paranoid.